# Listing registration profiles in the admin interface of django-registration with django-nonrel

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I've successfully installed django-nonrel, and django-registration on Google app engine, thanks for [this](http://joinwithjack.blogspot.com/2011/02/experiment-no-3-using-django.html) very useful article. However I have difficulties on listing the registration profiles ( visiting `/admin/registration/registrationprofile` ) in the admin interface, I got the following error, just in the deployed version.

```
 File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2324, in __query_result_hook
   str(exc) + '\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n' + yaml)

NeedIndexError: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: registration_registrationprofile
 properties:
 - name: __key__
   direction: desc
```

visiting `/admin/registration/registrationprofile/add` is just fine.

I had the same issue with one of my apps, but after a while it started working, don't know why.

What can be the problem?

**EDIT**

Strange, but now it's working. I guess it was because of my browser cache, or google servers needed more time to activate that index, don't know, maybe I'll try to find out later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says everythig. You must define primary key in registration_registrationprofile as index in index.yaml file:

```
indexes:
- kind: registration_registrationprofile
  properties:
  - name: __key__
  - direction: desc
```

Comment: This is in the index.yaml file, and it is serving, I checked it on app engine under datastore indexes. (I don't exceeded the quota too)